# How to set Delegation state in activiti

Tags: activiti

I created a workflow in activiti. When a task is pending then its delegationState or DELETE_REASON_ is showing NULL or the column is blank. When task is completed then it is showing Completed. How i can change this delegationState or DELETE_REASON_. 
 Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can change the delegation state of a task using the delegateTask method of the TaskService interface. This is usually done with a code like this:

execution.getEnginServices().getTaskService().delegateTask(taskId,"some.user")

Once delegated, the task is now in a "delegated" state. In order to send the task back to its original owner, you should use the resolveTask() method.

Both are described in the Javadoc and User´s Manual.

Comment: I dont want to "delegate" a task. I want that when task is present in user's tasklist then it will show "pending state" and when task got complete then it will show "completed state". In activiti table (ACT_HI_TASKINST ) , column (DELETE_REASON) is showing "completed state"  for completed task or "NULL state" for pending task.

Comment: You cannot use the DELETE_REASON column for that. This column is populated only when the task is removed from the ACT_RUN_TASKINST table.

On order to create a task list that displays the curren task state you should use the properties available in the HistoricTaskInstance. Something like that:

String state = taskInstance.getEndTime() !=null? "COMPLETE":"PENDING"

Comment: thank you for your help...But if i want to show this in activiti then how i can show it. Any idea.??

Comment: What do you mean by "show in activiti" ? Activiti itself is just a library. The GUI is provided either by the activiti-explorer webapp or one you develop by yourself. Which is your case ?

Comment: I am talking about GUI provided by activiti-explorer webapp.

Comment: In this case you have to change the app code so it shows the way you want. Messing with the DB or changing Activiti´s core so it shows a different value for the 'delete reason' column is a bad idea....

Comment: okay...Thanks for your help..:-)

Comment: EndTime() is not getting as a function...:-(

Comment: Please check the javadoc for the HistoricTaskInstance class.
http://activiti.org/javadocs/org/activiti/engine/history/HistoricTaskInstance.html

The method getEndTime is there for sure.